# Duplicate backup files, and name of the same

Tags: php

My code creates a backup file, of the data that are present inside the db, after 7 days, I wanted to know, if I do a test, of data that should not be deleted, so to speak two records, with today's date they they are not properly eliminated, but anyway a backup file is created, and I don't want this, I want the backup file to be created only when the deletion occurs, and then I tried to rename the backup file, because at its creation I would like it to be saved with the date on which the backup was made but I skip everything and I don't understand why

> I only want the backup file to be created if there are results in the database that will be deleted.
>
> I want the backup file to have the current date as the file name.

```
<?php

    //Start the session
    session_start();

    //Include connection
    include 'connessione.php';

    $query = $connessione->query("
        SELECT *
        FROM utenti 
        WHERE data_password < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
    ");

    $results = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $ok = json_encode( $results );

    function makeDirectory($path, $mode) 
    {
        $return = mkdir($path, $mode, true);
        return $return === true || is_dir($path);
    }

    //Create the directory for backup files.
    $path = 'backup_LOG';
    $mode = 0777;
    $risultato = makeDirectory($path, $mode);

    //Put those results in a file (create if file not exist)
    $fileName = 'backup_LOG/backup_file_' . time() . '.txt';
    $file = fopen( $fileName , 'a'  );
    fwrite( $file, $ok );
    fclose( $file );
    
    if (count($results) > 0) {
        // @todo backup the data

        // delete fetched rows
        $firstId = reset($results)['data_password'];
        $lastId  = end($results)['data_password'];
        $stmt = $connessione->prepare("DELETE FROM utenti WHERE data_password < DATE_SUB(NOW() , INTERVAL 7 DAY)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $firstId, $lastId);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you move the code that is just below `//Put those results in a file` comment, put it inside the `if()`, now it will only be created if `count($results) > 0`. To make the filename include the date, change `time()` to `date( 'Y_m_d' )`

Comment: @HarveyFletcher I tried to change time in date, but then I answered in the backup file with boolean character ie with a nice 1, I'm glad that you tell me yes, but there is not my backup

Comment: @HarveyFletcher nor if I include the backup creation part under the if loop, however if I launch the page it creates backup files for me